# truffle migrate doesnt do anything

Tags: tokens, ganache, nft

**Update**: I ran `truffle develop` and it was still conencted to my old ganache blockchain. How do I update it?

whenever I run `truffle migrate` it compiles my contracts then just ends, it doesn't run the migrations. Even with `--reset`, it still doesn't update anything. It just says

```
Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Emscripten.clang
```

truffle-config.js

```
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7546,
      network_id: "*"
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
};
```

The migration I added:
2_deploy_contract.js

```
module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(NftTest);
};
```

My Ganache:
[image: My Ganache]

Note: this is my second NFT project (the first one, I was following some youtube tutorial). My first guess is there's some sort of overlap maybe? but I'm not really sure. Maybe there's something that I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

the `development` name is special, it's used when no network is provided in the command so with the command `migrate` you are connecting on port 7546.

I see ganache listening on 7545 in your screen.

Maybe you could try something similar:

```
        ganache: {
            host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
            port: 7545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
            network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
        },
```

and then try running
`truffle migrate --reset --network=ganache`

(or change the port in your truffle-config file)

Comment: it still doesnt work, and truffle is still connecting to an older ganache chain. And I changed the port back to 7545, I was playing around with it, thinking it might fix it or something.